# Python Support for Windows 7 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, installation, windows-7, visual-studio-2017

I have 2 options here: I can go to Python's website and select the link that says python for windows and download the language from there, and then use any supported compiler-interpreter linker and debugger for it. The other alternative is I can choose Python Deployment from Visual Studio's 2017 Installer. The current version in the Visual Studio installer for Python is 3.6.3 which I'm fairly sure that if I install it into Visual Studio and there are any updates Visual Studio will let me know. If I choose to download Python from their website there newest version is 3.6.5. I'm not too concerned about the differences in the versions. I just need to have a working version of the language with a supported compiler - interpreter...

Is there any major difference from choosing the one over the other? I read through the MS docs about their tools for Visual Studio on Python and they do claim that if you already have it installed there is no need to check the boxes to install the core language through their installer as it will automatically detect if you have Python installed. For Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2017 which is more preferable: downloading Python from their website directly and then integrating it into Visual Studio; or just letting Visual Studio install its version for me? I am new to python; but I need a working version of it in order to build binaries for MPIR - MPFR - MPFRCPP.

The reason I asked is if I chose to install all the available options under Visual Studio it is about 18GB in size which would include Python's tools and different versions of Anaconda. However the Visual Studio documents also stated if you decide to use Python for Data Science to also select the Data Science & Analytical Applications from the workloads section. This would add about another 2GB. This would take some time to download and install postponing any and all of my project developments. I just want to know what I'm in store for and what is the better of my two options.

Answer (score 1):

> For Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2017 which is more preferable: downloading Python from their website directly and then integrating it into Visual Studio; or just letting Visual Studio install its version for me?

Just let Visual Studio 2017 download it for you, it is much more easy, but still the choice still depends on you because installing it through VS or their Website is likely the same.

Comment: Thank you; I was thinking that myself; but just wanted to be sure. I didn't know if there would be any missing dependencies between one or the other for what I'm trying to do. This all started because I was trying to use boost's multi precision library; and it relies on GMP where there is very little to almost no support of gmp on windows. There are some tricks that involve using mingw cygwn; but since I have visual studio 2017; I don't really want or need either of them. I also can not use the "python scripts" to configure the settings to build MPIR - MPFR...

Comment: which are forked wrapper libraries based off of gmp. So now i'm in the process of gathering all the tools I need first and installing them; I already have vyasm installed for the assembly support of MPIR-MPFR libraries, but need python now. Then I have a lot of work to do to get my directories, environment variables and projects settings correct to build the dlls or libs I need. This has been about  3-4 day process now.

Comment: Unlike Downloading python on their website, Visual Studio mostly downloads almost all tools/dependencies you need depending on the checkboxes/preferences you tick on the installer.

Comment: Yeah I have it up and working; however I'm completely use to c++ and brand new to python. Went through a couple of brief tutorials... Right now I'm trying to determine which `compiler` specific build of `mpir` I should be using. My motherboard code name is Intel `Skyburg`, my motherboard chipset code name is `Eaglelake` and my processor alias is `Yorkfield`. I have an Intel DP45SG mother board with P45 chipset running a QuadCore Intel Core 2 Quad Q9650, 3000 MHz (9 x 333). I do not see any of those names in the list except for basic core2 & core2_penryn

Comment: I see sandybridge, sandybridge_ivybridge, skylake, skylake_avx... This is for asm instruction optimizations.

Comment: I figured out how to get the python shell script up to load the mpir_config.py file; but being new to python, I don't know how to "use" it... pass it parameters or selections...

Comment: Just watch a couple of tutorials.

Comment: Yeah; it'll take me a little bit to get use to Python coming from C++. Eventually I'll get the hang of it; but being expected to know it to build C & C++ libraries when you are native to C languages... That's the conundrum...  Almost like a farming telling a 1 day old calf to produce him some milk!

Comment: Just think of it as C++ but without curly braces xD

Comment: I noticed that, and terminating lines aren't `;` some of them are `:` and some are just plain returns. Also I'm use to `#include` as opposed to `import` & `export`.

Comment: Once I get use to python, with visual studio the integration between both c++ and python can be very powerful especially with template meta programming.